# How to export a snapshot of VM before deleting my GCP account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was developing a Proof of Concept with GCP, I am done for now and I need to delete my account. But before I need to make a copy of VM as we are planning to move into production. I made a snapshot of VM, how can I export it to my local server/machine?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/export / https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can’t download a snapshot from your VM instance due to [snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/snapshots) are incremental backups from your persistent disks. But you can download a custom image from your VM instance.

These are the steps I used:

- [**Create the image**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#create_image)

1. [Stop your instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#stopping_an_instance)
2. In the Google Cloud Console, go to the [Create an image page.](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/imagesAdd)
3. Fill the blanks (I left all the default values for my test)
4. Click **Create** to create the image.

- [**Export your image**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image#exporting_an_image_with_a_single_command)

1. In the Google Cloud Console, go to the [Images](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/images) page.
2. Click the name of the image that you want to export to go to the image details page.
3. From the image details page, click **Export**

[image]

4. Select the image format needed.
5. Choose the Cloud Storage location to export your image or create a new one in the menu that appears at the right.
6. Click Export to conclude the process.

- **Download the image**

1. In the Google Cloud Console, go to the [Cloud Storage Browser](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser)
2. Click the name of the Bucket where you stored your image
3. And to **download the Image to your local server/machine** click on the Download button.

[image]

Comment: Any idea why my image wouldn't have an export button?
I've tried following this, but when viewing my new image details there is no "Export" (or edit) button. I'm an admin user so I don't expect permissions to be the issue. Thanks for this, though!

Comment: I found my issue: I was creating _machine images_ via [...] > [Create new machine image] on my VM instance. Apparently "Machine images" ( https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/machineImages ) are separate from "Images" linked in the answer. When I create an Image from the Images page, I can export as described. No idea why both of these exist, it's super confusing.